# Can't find nested url: no route matched URL

Tags: ember.js

Ember shows me the following error: Uncaught Error: No route matched the URL '/users'

```
Sks.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  redirect: ->
    this.transitionTo 'users'

Sks.Router.map ->
  this.resource 'users', path: 'users/:user_id'

Sks.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    this.controllerFor('users').set 'content', Sks.User.find()
    this.controllerFor('currentUser').set 'content', Sks.CurrentUser.find 1
    this.controllerFor('top').set 'content', Sks.Top.find()
    this.controllerFor('hamsters').set 'content', Sks.Hamster.find()
```

Everything works when I remove the dynamic segment.

Version: v1.0.0-rc.1-78-gd4e6a5c

edit#1
added IndexRoute

Comment: When does this error occur?

Comment: uhmm, `this.resource 'users', path: 'users/:user_id'` only sets a route for URLs like "/users/:something", doesn't it? so you'll have to define something like `this.resource 'users2', path: 'users'` to get rid of the problem, i think.

Comment: @TeddyZeenny when I start an app; I added IndexRoute if it helps

Comment: The problem is as @FinnMacCool said, you can't transition to `users` without passing a `user` record with it.  By defining it with a dynamic segment, the route cannot exist without a record passed to it.

Comment: actually, `/:user_id` is part of the URL the `UsersRoute` is defined for and `/users` is a separate URL.

Answer (score 0):

In Ember, collections and items actually use separate routes. Here's how I do it:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('contacts', { path: '/contacts' });
    this.resource('contact', { path: '/contact/:contact_id' });
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function () {
        this.replaceWith('contacts');
    }
});

App.ContactsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return App.Contact.find();  
    }
});

App.ContactRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return App.Contact.find(params.contact_id);  
    }
});
```

Here's a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ekidd/VKewU/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I should have RTM :)

```
Sks.Router.map ->
  this.resource 'users', ->
    this.resource 'user', path: ':user_id'
```